# Asking Excel to retrieve and match large amounts of data for me from another/same sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet, data-retrieval

I have a population of animals. I want to calculate the age the mother of each individual had when that individual was born.

In my spreadsheet with data, I have (among other things I want to test) the ID of each individual, the date of birth of that individual and its mother ID. Note that the Mother IDs are the same value as some individual IDs because, in my population, some individuals are both a mother and offspring (multigenerational).

The spreadsheet looks like in the image. Note that the examples I have posted some the mother/dams are wild animals and their ID's are unknown.

My challenge is how do I will enter the date of birth of each mother in the row of each individual. I have 1700 individuals and computing this by hand seems crazy. Is it possible to ask Excel to retrieve the DoB of the dam? I have been trying some formulas but so far without success. I also tried to create another sheet with only the IDs and dates of birth and asking excel to retrieve the date of birth (from that other sheet) if in the column "Dam" is a specific number (ID).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p65F.png)

So ideally I want to link the following data:

```
Individual ID ---- DoB ---- Dam ---- Dam's DoB
```

Ideally I also would like to have a suggestion on how can I input the birth rank of each individual (1st child, 2nd child...) and the interval between births of the same female (in years) in a automated way.

Comment: Try giving us some data we can copy and work with instead of an image.

Comment: ^ + the mother ID and enough examples to enable testing / an expected output

Comment: sorry, new member here. Any suggestions on how can I share a bunch of data as examples?

Comment: I added a new picture that might help to explain, the dam of the animal 10 is animal 4.

Comment: You talk about large amounts of data. Excel has a maximum amount of 1,048,576 rows. In case your amount of data is larger than that, you might look for another tool.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will give the Dam ID if put in row 2 to start with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$D,MATCH($D2,$A:$A,0),MATCH("Date of Birth",$A$1:$D$1,0)),"")
```

Comment: This formula works, but the cells come up blank. I believe it is because of the "" at the end of the function. I appreciate the effort to help! It is still not giving the desired result

Comment: It will only come up blank if 1. the formula isn't working based on your table layout, or 2. the Dam ID is not in the UniqueID column..... you can use this =INDEX($A:$D,MATCH($D2,$A:$A,0),MATCH("Date of Birth",$A$1:$D$1,0))

Comment: My table layout is just like the one in the picture I shared. How do you suggest to make it differently?

Comment: Sorry I meant are the table columns aligned A to D? Screenshot doesn’t show. Thanks

Comment: Yes they are. A to D

Comment: https://exceljet.net/articles/index-and-match I am looking at this, but I do find a way to make it work for me.

Comment: I managed to make it work. The formation of the cells was different (one was text and the other a number, so no exact match could be found). Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Great stuff. I did look into the other pieces you asked for but it seems RANK() cannot be used with FILTER(). Need to find another way of returning an array filtered on ‘Dam ID’ into the rank function.

Comment: I found a way to do the other 2!

Comment: Well done! Please share as an answer